# While loading the page, hide and not load content of chosen div. On click load chosen div and its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I've tried to googling for it, but seems like that it is not my strongest part.

Example: I have a div with embed a video inside, but to show that video I have to click first on div which opens and shows the video. The problem is that it loads on pageload. It makes browser lags while there is more than 4-5 of those div with videos. How can I make it to not load withing pageload, but only when a div is clicked and unload its content when it is clicked again.

```
$('.cont').hide();


$('h4').click(function () {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.cont');
    if ($answer.is(':hidden')) {
        $answer.show();
    } else {
        $answer.hide();
    }
});
```

This is what I have, but it is not as I described it

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald edited

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<iframe new-src="http://linktoadditionalcode">Update your Browser!</iframe>
<a href="javascript:load(this)">Load</a>
<a href="javascript:unload(this)">Unload</a>
</div>
<script>
function load(elem){
frame=elem.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
frame.src=frame.new-src;
}
function unload(elem){
frame=elem.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
frame.src="";
}
</script>
```

this loads/unloads the iframe. While your code just hides it, this completely loads/nloads it.